# Laravel Eloquent How to apply condition on "with" datas on the output?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

here my code :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with(
            [
            'service' => function($service) use($searchService) {
                $service->select(['id','name'])->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
            },
            'facility' => function($facility) use($searchPartenaire) {
                $facility->select(['id','name'])->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
            }
            ]
        )
            ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
            ->simplePaginate(50);

        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];
```

The problem is that in the output of all datas where "service" and "facility" names are not equal on the $searchService and $searchPartenaire the values are replaced by "null".
So i don't want to have values in the output where the search variables are not equals.

Thank you.

Comment: Do u means if the $service not equal on $searchService, that records still comes out, but the name is replaced by null?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes, exactly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```php
 $prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility');

        $prestations->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
            $query->Where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchPartenaire . '%');
        });

        $prestations->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
            $query->Where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchPartenaire . '%');
        });

        $prestations->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
            ->simplePaginate(50);

        return $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];
```

1st create instances of **Prestation**  `$prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility')`

then apply the condtion this is good approach in seach

Comment: Thank's for your suggest, i have a problem with this : a infinite loop of http request

Comment: @Tony then retrun it . have used this in my project it's works for me

Answer (score 0):

Here my code after Kamlesh Paul suggestion :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility');

        $prestations->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
            $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
        });

        $prestations->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
            $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
        });

        $prestations->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
            ->simplePaginate(50);

        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];

        return $res;
```

But there is an infinite calls of http request, i think that the problem is when the where don't find an equal name, anyone have a suggest ? 
Thank's.

Comment: how you knows infinite loop occur .?

Comment: I see this in the devtools (from navigator), it's not a loop it's infinite request calls.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a solution very similar :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility')
            ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
            $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
            })  
            ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
                $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
            })
                ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
                ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
                ->simplePaginate(50); 

        $res = [
            'results' => $prestations,
            'total' => Prestation::all()->count(),
        ];
```

Thank's for your help.